# How to send Cutomised output through RUNDECK

Tags: email, push-notification, output, rundeck

I have set my `rundeck-config.groovy` in my config folder and this is included in my profile file as well.

My Groovy file:

```
grails.mail.default.from="pavan@gmail.com" grails {  mail {host = "smtp.gmail.com"   username = "pavan@gmail.com"    port = 587    password = "ghsdkexgbnsowmdsu"    props =["mail.smtp.starttls.enable":"true", "mail.smtp.port":587, "mail.smtp.auth":"true"]  }}
```

when i run my `RUNDECK` job i am recieving email notification, but the email i recieve has all the details, logs, commands used, even code which i dont want the recipent to see

i want to customise it and show only the output result in message body.

example: Checking Health of a server

```
url = "curl -kv https://vn2-lpgdmt-capp99.rno.vzon.com:8990/health/check"
```

in the output i only want to show as

`https://vn2-lpgdmt-capp99.rno.vzon.com:8990/health/check = Status:200 ok`

kindly help, what plugins i might have to add or anything

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [custom template](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/email-settings.html#custom-email-templates) with your [email notification](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/email-settings.html#notification-email-settings) that prints the output using `${logouput.data}` to print the output, I leave an example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='myurl' value='http://www.google.com' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>322beb61-c701-4758-b58f-55da63953dee</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>CheckStatusExample</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <notification>
      <onsuccess>
        <email attachLog='true' attachLogInline='true' recipients='devopsteam@example.net' subject='Success!' />
      </onsuccess>
    </notification>
    <notifyAvgDurationThreshold />
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "@option.myurl@=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null @option.myurl@)"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>322beb61-c701-4758-b58f-55da63953dee</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

With this HTML template:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Data: ${logoutput.data}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsvLY.jpg) the result on Rundeck, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB2ze.jpg) on the email inbox.

Comment: Thank you this helped and it worked, But the output in HTML came in a single line, when i am checking for multiple servers, i want it come in different lines rather come in a single line, i edited in my source code with <br>, i was thinking if i could do this in HTML as well, is it possible? if yes please share a example, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to pass a captured Global Log Filters variable like ${data.app_host} into a mail template like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Data: ${data.app_host}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```